# Finding probabilities from ambiguous moment generating functions

Tags: probability, random-variables, moment-generating-functions

Assume that the random variable $X$ has moment generating function,

$M_X(t) = \frac{1}{6}e^{-2t} + \frac{1}{5}e^{-t} + \frac{3}{10}e^{t} + \frac{1}{3}e^{2t}$

Find $Pr(|X| \leq 1)$.

I've tried using the moment generating function technique by going over known distributions to see if I am some how successful in finding which distribution this MGF belongs to but haven't succeeded.

Comment: Here you can read the probabilities directly from $M_X(t)=\sum_x e^{tx}P(X=x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ takes the values $-2, -1,1,2$ with probabilities $\frac 1 6, \frac 1 5, \frac 3 {10}$ and $\frac 1 3$ respectively. Hence $P(|X| \leq 1)=P(X=1)+P(X=-1)=\frac 1 5+ \frac 3 {10}=\frac 1  2$.

Comment: Hey, could you please explain why X  takes the values −2,−1,1,2 with probabilities $\frac{1}{6}, \frac{1}{5}, \frac{3}{10} and \frac{1}{3}$ respectively?

Comment: OH..... Okay, I see. Thanks!

Comment: @CraigLutic $\sum p_n e^{tc_n}$ is the MGF function of the random variable taking values $c_1,c_2,...$ with probabilities $p_1,p_2,...$.

Comment: Hey Kavi, I was thinking about this question again. The question (in my book) doesn't specify if X is continuous or discrete. If it is discrete than the probabilities can be read off as you've shown, but is there a way we can be sure that X isn't continuous, or is that just a mistake in question ambiguity?

Comment: A random variable with the given MGF is necessarily discrete.